# How do I create a django form that allows me to edit a model with a reverse manytomany relationship?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-admin

I am trying to make a page that displays a word, its meanings, and associated sentences. I would like these to be displayed in a form that I can can edit and then save the changes into the database. Additionally, I would like to be able to display multiple forms on the page. So if I had 5 words, I would get 5 forms on the page with areas for the word, meanings, and sentences, all of which would be editable.

I have been able to create a form with the word and its meanings. However, I have been unsuccessful in finding a way to display the associated sentences (which has a ManyToMany relationship to my Word class) using forms.

I've read about modelformset_factory, BaseFormSet and I know you can pass a queryset to create multiple forms. However, I am struggling to fit them all together to create the form I want. When I try to use queryset with the MeaningsForm it always throws an error because it only accepts a single object vs a queryset object.

Here is the code I have currently that simply displays a word and its associated meanings. If there was a way to do what I want with an admin view that would be even better. Any help/advice would be appreciated.

*models.py*

```
class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length = 300)

class Sentence(models.Model):
    sentence = models.TextField(null=True)
    word = models.ManyToManyField(Word)

class WordMeanings(models.Model):
    word = models.ForeignKey(Word)
    meaning = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
```

*forms.py*

```
class WordsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Words 
        fields = ('word',)

class MeaningsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WordMeanings 
        fields = ('meaning',)
```

*views.py*

```
def sentence_review(request):
    word = Words.objects.get(id=10)
    meaningset= inlineformset_factory(Word, WordMeanings, fields=('meaning',))
    meaningset = meaningset(instance=word)
    word_form = WordsForm(instance=word)
    return render(request, 'sentence_review.html', {"wordform": word_form, "meaningset_form": meaningset} )
```

Comment: Are you planning to use the same Sentence for multiple words? Because thats what you have right now. If not, perhaps, you should consider having the Sentence as a part of your Word model. Only if you are planning on having multiple sentences for the same word, then I would create the Sentence model. JMHO

Comment: Yes, I am currently using the same sentence for multiple words. In retrospect I probably should have put the many to many relationship on the Word model; however, I already have a lot of data in a database and I don't know how easy that would be to change which is why I'm looking for alternative solutions. @WayBehind

Comment: "Alternative" solution is not a good fix for a poorly designed database. Transferring data between tables is very easy and you should start with a good database design. Any kind of early shortcuts will bite you in the long term. Not worth it. Also editing 3 different models (db tables) through one form is probably not a good idea. You can use Ajax for some instant updates etc.